# Is there anyway to move a partition on the outer platter of the disk closer to the inner spindle?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I have a desktop hard drive that has 640GB, a C partition that is 25GB and the rest of the space is in partition D for data.

Now my problem is some how the OS partition is showing on the very last part of the Disk Management. And it's getting very slow to boot up the OS (Windows 7)

Is there any tool I can use to physically move the partition from the outer platter to the inner closer to the spindle? Because I know that will improve the performance dramatically.

Answer (score 3):

Only by re-creating the partitions—having backed up the content first of course. There are tools that can help (whether they can swap the positions will depend on the product).

*But*:

> I know that will improve the performance dramatically

This is *not* true. Modern hard disks pack more sectors into the outer tracks of the disk, so linear read and write performance doesn't change much across the disk. What will slow things down will be having to seek backwards and forwards from one edge to the other: but with a partition not occupying the whole disk this will not happen (and the answer would be to defragment the disk: a good idea and Windows 7 will do this automatically on a scheduler).

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, i thought it might be something along the line to re-partition the entire disk. The problem is I have data on it and it's gonna take a long time to backup everything :(

Comment: Zone Bit Recording threw out all that old cargo cult stuff about optimizing old MFM and RLL hard drives with interleaves, moving stuff radially for performance, et.al. We're not in Kansas anymore...